# convert html tags/hyperlink to simple text in python3

Tags: python-3.x

how can I convert this below html tagged value to normal string using python3.

`<http:\\/\\/aziz.example.com|aziz.example.com>`

I want to convert above html wrapped link to simple text like.

`aziz.example.com`

Comment: `import re;`  `list(set(re.findall(r'\w+\.\w+\.\w+','<http:\\/\\/aziz.example.com|aziz.example.com>')))[0]`

Comment: can this `set` be removed? it returns like
`{'aziz.example.com'}`

Comment: See the updated post

Comment: @PKumar any examples using re.match instead of re.findall ???